# Regex to split by special characters with exceptions JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I am very new to regular expressions and Im having difficulties with this one:

I want to split a String when found this patern  but also this one "text here" and this one "text here"^^ (this should be considered as one in the output). 
Note these symbols: ^^
The three cases can be repeated each many times or can be one after the other and are always separated by spaces. 
Example:

> <\herewouldbeurl> "HEY THERE" "Asioc-project.org/."^^<\anotherurl/>

would produce: 
1.<\herewouldbeurl>
2."HEY THERE"
3."Asioc-project.org/."^^<\anotherurl/>

Ive found this: "\s+(?=(?:(?<=[a-zA-Z])\"(?=[A-Za-z])|\"[^\"]*\"|[^\"])*$)" but does not work for the third case.

Any ideas?

Comment: *"The three cases"*? You only listed two cases.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `split()`. Use a `find()` loop.

```
String input = "<\\herewouldbeurl> \"HEY THERE\" \"Asioc-project.org/.\"^^<\\anotherurl/>";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\".*?\"(?:\\^\\^)?");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
int start = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    String s = input.substring(start, m.start()).trim();
    if (! s.isEmpty())
        System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(m.group());
    start = m.end();
}
String s = input.substring(start).trim();
if (! s.isEmpty())
    System.out.println(s);
```

*Output*

```
<\herewouldbeurl>
"HEY THERE"
"Asioc-project.org/."^^
<\anotherurl/>
```